# Multiple Payments definition for Billing Plan

Tags: php, paypal, recurring-billing, paypal-rest-sdk

I'm doing an application that requires recurring profile. But their business model consist on 1 trial period and 2 regular periods, one for a couple of days and other for monthly infinite.

```
{  
   "name":"Regular Membership Billing Plan",
   "description":"This plan is for regular membership\r\n7 days trial\r\nBilling 23 days after trial\r\ninfinite montly",
   "type":"INFINITE",
   "payment_definitions":[  
      {  
         "name":"7 days trial regular product",
         "type":"TRIAL",
         "frequency":"WEEK",
         "frequency_interval":"1",
         "cycles":"1",
         "amount":{  
            "value":"2",
            "currency":"USD"
         }
      },
      {  
         "name":"23 days after trial regular product",
         "type":"REGULAR",
         "frequency":"DAY",
         "frequency_interval":"23",
         "cycles":"1",
         "amount":{  
            "value":"5",
            "currency":"USD"
         }
      },
      {  
         "name":"Monthly regular product",
         "type":"REGULAR",
         "frequency":"MONTH",
         "frequency_interval":"1",
         "cycles":"0",
         "amount":{  
            "value":"7.99",
            "currency":"USD"
         }
      }
   ]
}
```

I'm getting this error from the response:

```
"Payment definitions are invalid. Valid parameters are REGULAR or combination of TRIAL and REGULAR."
```

which makes me think that is not possible to have multiple regular payments definition on the same plan.

Is there a way for me to do something similar?

Comment: I know this is a few months old, but why not create 2 billing plans. One with the 7 day trail, and the 23 day extension as a regular payment. And the second with a 30 day free trial, and the infinite billing cycle.  Then once that expires, prevent them from repurchasing the first billing (using something like Rules in Drupal - don't know what system you are using)  and then the second billing plan should kick in. (If paypal does not allow you two sign up 2 agreements at once, do not put the trial period on the second and sign them up immediately once they log in after the first 30 days.)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Sadly, it seems like is not possible with the paypal platform:

> The current release of the Recurring Payments API has the following
> limitations:
>
> - A profile can have at most one optional trial period and a single regular payment period.
> - The profile start date may not be earlier than the profile creation date.

[Paypal Recurring Billing](https://developer.paypal.com/docs/classic/express-checkout/integration-guide/ECRecurringPayments/)